# Query child model with mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm updating the mongoose version from 5 to 6 and found a change in the behavior.

This is a small example:
We have two models

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ text: String });
const Message = mongoose.model('Message', MessageSchema);

const Notification = Message.discriminator(
    'Notification',
    new mongoose.Schema({important: Boolean})
);
```

And let's say, we create two documents:

```
const m = new Message({text: 'Some text 1'});
await m.save();

const n = new Notification({important: true, text: 'Some text'});
await n.save();
```

And we run this query:

```
await Message.find({important: true})
```

In mongoose v5 the query will use `important` in spite of it not being declared in the `Message` schema. And the result will be just one document.

However, in the new version, it will ignore important if you query `Messages`, and will return all the documents, because without `important` query is just {}.

**My question is, how can I achieve the same behavior with the new version?**

I know that I could use the `Notification` model instead of `Messages`, but image if there were several models like `Notification` (children of `Message`), that had `important` in them, and I wanted to search in all of them.

Comment: Did you find an answer ? I have the exact problem ....

Comment: @SévrainCHEA I ended up just querying Notification directly. You could also try to use mongodb driver instead of mongoose model: 

`mongoose.connection.collections.message.findMany({important: true});`

Keep in mind this will return a MongoDB cursor, instead of an array of mongoose models